# How to Traverse a Firebase Structure in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to traverse the Firebase schema to get data for each `workouts` & display it in a RecyclerView.
Now I can't traverse the Schema in the Firebase using the listener & get it via POJO Class called `Program`.

**JSON From Firebase**

```
{
  "subscriptions" : {
    "han@gmail,com" : {
      "-KDnhRwHjssOejrqyenP" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "This workout can be done while on the phone!",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Hello Workouts",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Jumping Jacks", "Wall sit", "Pushups", "Sit-ups", "Step ups", "Squats", "Tricep dips on chair", "Plank", "High Knees running in place", "Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "Butt Kickers", "Lying Triceps Lifts", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Arm Clap", "Overhead Press", "Power Circles", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Reverse Plank", "Spiderman Push-up", "T Raise", "Tricep Dips", "Wall Push-ups", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpees" ]
        }
      },
      "-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "This workout can be done by a BABUJI",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Indian Workouts",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Jackknives", "Plyo Lunges", "Plyo Squats", "Single leg plank (alternate per round)", "Plyo Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Weighted side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Press", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Spiderman Push-up", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpee Pushups" ]
        }
      }
    },
    "obama@gmsil,com" : {
      "-KDnfjROKeFAL9wccsxY" : {
        "category" : "Mobility",
        "goal" : "afternoon body weight workout",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Afternoon HiiT",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Squats", "Lunges", "Diamond Push-ups", "Lying Triceps Lifts" ]
        }
      },
      "-KDps90Dn6XtJc6Co00b" : {
        "category" : "Strength",
        "goal" : "goal",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "title",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Jackknives", "Plyo Lunges", "Plyo Squats", "Single leg plank (alternate per round)", "Plyo Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Weighted side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Press", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Spiderman Push-up", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpee Pushups" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

**Listener CODE**

```
    public void FB(){
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue());
    //Program post = proSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
```

**LOGCAT**

> 03-28 08:52:53.966 23584-23584/com.android.sam I/System.out: {-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92={weeks={week1=[Diamond Pushups, Jackknives, Plyo Lunges, Plyo Squats, Single leg plank (alternate per round), Plyo Lunges, Pushup and rotation, Weighted side plank (alternate per round), Alternating Push-Up Plank, Chest Expander, Diamond Push-ups, Dive Bomber Push-ups, One Arm Side Push-up, Overhead Press, Push-up and Rotation, T Push-ups, Spiderman Push-up, Wide Arm Push-ups, Burpee Pushups]}, title=Indian Workouts, category=Strength, length=1, goal=This workout can be done by a BABUJI}, -KDnhRwHjssOejrqyenP={weeks={week1=[High Knees, Jumping Jacks, Wall sit, Pushups, Sit-ups, Step ups, Squats, Tricep dips on chair, Plank, High Knees running in place, Lunges, Pushup and rotation, Side plank (alternate per round), Alternating Push-Up Plank, Chest Expander, Diamond Push-ups, Dive Bomber Push-ups, Butt Kickers, Lying Triceps Lifts, One Arm Side Push-up, Overhead Arm Clap, Overhead Press, Power Circles, Push-up and Rotation, T Push-ups, Reverse Plank, Spiderman Push-up, T Raise, Tricep Dips, Wall Push-ups, Wide Arm Push-ups, Burpees]}, title=Hello Workouts, category=Strength, length=1, goal=This workout can be done while on the phone!}}
>
> 03-28 08:52:53.967 23584-23584/com.android.sam I/System.out: {-KDnfjROKeFAL9wccsxY={weeks={week1=[High Knees, Squats, Lunges, Diamond Push-ups, Lying Triceps Lifts]}, title=Afternoon HiiT, category=Mobility, length=1, goal=afternoon body weight workout}, -KDps90Dn6XtJc6Co00b={weeks={week1=[Diamond Pushups, Jackknives, Plyo Lunges, Plyo Squats, Single leg plank (alternate per round), Plyo Lunges, Pushup and rotation, Weighted side plank (alternate per round), Alternating Push-Up Plank, Chest Expander, Diamond Push-ups, Dive Bomber Push-ups, One Arm Side Push-up, Overhead Press, Push-up and Rotation, T Push-ups, Spiderman Push-up, Wide Arm Push-ups, Burpee Pushups]}, title=title, category=Strength, length=1, goal=goal}}

**Program.java**

```
public class Program {
    private String title;

    private String goal;

    private String category;

    private int length;

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> weeks;

    /**
     * Required public constructor
     */
    public Program() {
    }

    public Program(String title, String goal,  String category, int length, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> weeks) {
        this.title = title;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.category = category;
        this.length = length;
        this.weeks = weeks;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getweeks() {
        return weeks;
    }    
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Did you try making any mapping yet?

Comment: I have a POJO class called Program to do the mapping. But i can't traverse & get the data inside the Push ID?

Comment: I'm guessing it'll be a case of `DataSnapshot.forEach()`, but it's all still very unclear. What node in the JSON does a `Program` class map to? What does the `Program` class look like (add what you already have for it to the question)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Each Workout is mapped to the Program POJO. Added POJO to the Question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ReazMurshed said, you're almost there. But you're failing to iterate over one level in your tree. It seems that ref is pointing to the `subscriptions` node in your JSON. Under that you have users and then you have the push ids. So you'll need to do a double loop:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener) {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot programSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          Program program = programSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
      }
    }
  }

  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

  }
});
```

Comment: I tried the double loop yesterday. But I haven't tried with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: The double loop would work the same with `addValueEventListener()`. But when using a `addChildEventListener()` you'd only need a single loop, since the callback would be triggered with a `DataSnapshot` of each individual user already.

Comment: Very neat answer. First I couldn't understand his problem completely. Though I didn't come up with this solution you've got there. I was thinking of binding the node in a list of `Program` class. Will that work? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Isn't that what I do now? I was trying to create a `Users` class with a map of `Program`s in there, but so far couldn't get it to work. It must be possible, but apparently it's not feasible on Monday morning.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. You just need to add `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` listener with your reference to iterate through the data associated with the reference node. Here's an example of how it could be done.

In your case, lets just declare a class named `ProgramList`

```
public class ProgramList {
    public List<Program> mProgramList;
}
```

Now get reference to the to the email address node and add a listener to it.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener) {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot programSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final ProgramList mProgramList = programSnapshot.getValue(ProgramList.class);

                // Now iterate through the list here. 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

You might check the [firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) for retrieving data in android again. [This is an example](https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts) of a same database structure like you have here.

Comment: It doesn't work because we got to traverse after the Push ID. So that it can fetch the data from there. For now, it is including the push ID in the snapshot. So it is returning "Failed to bounce to type" Exception!

Comment: "Failed to bounce to type" means your Program POJO is not identical to the one you used in the Firebase database. Remove your getters and setters from your POJO and then try again.

Comment: Unrecognized field "-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92" (class com.android.sam), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

Comment: So, from your comment, I'm guessing that your `ref` is pointed to the node of email address. So somehow you need to point to the `-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92` key to bind the response from that reference node to `Program` class. I think you need to redesign your Firebase database to have a specific value for the `KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92` key to serve your purpose.

Comment: Is there any way to do traverse without redesigning the schema?

Comment: I've read the firebase documentation again. I see nothing wrong with your schema. Just get the reference of the email address and you'll get the list of programs in the call of `getValue`. See my edited answer.