# Firebase fetching results 2 different outputs on emulator and Android device

Tags: java, android, firebase

Here is what is stored in Firebase:

```
  "73668" : {
    "id" : "73668",
    "price" : "Price",
    "product1" : "1. Product 1",
    "product2" : "2. Product 2",
    "product3" : "3. Product 3",
    "status" : "not ready"
  },
  "a2521" : {
    "id" : "a2521",
    "price" : "Price",
    "product1" : "1. Product 1",
    "product2" : "2. Product 2",
    "product3" : "3. Product 3",
    "status" : "not ready"
  },
  "a719b" : {
    "id" : "a719b",
    "price" : "Price",
    "product1" : "1. Product 4",
    "product2" : "2. Product 5",
    "product3" : "3. Product 6",
    "status" : "not ready"
  }
}
```

Here is how it was fetched in the application:
[image]

The code I am using:

```
public ArrayList<Order> getOrders() {

  final Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://torrid-heat-2650.firebaseio.com/orders");
  myFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setProduct1(child.child("product1").getValue().toString());
        order.setProduct2(child.child("product2").getValue().toString());
        order.setProduct3(child.child("product3").getValue().toString());
        order.setId(child.child("id").getValue().toString());
        order.setPrice(child.child("price").getValue().toString());

        itemsList.add(order);
      }
    }

    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }

  });
  System.out.println(itemsList.size());
  return itemsList;
}
```

The same operation returns empty arraylist on the Android device. The interesting thing is that it outputs 0 in both cases, however returns non-null arraylist. What could result 2 different outputs in the same code? Thank you.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Yes you need to edit your question with the JSON tree which makes it more solvable in case of solving firebase problems. But, anyway, I would like to suggest something more. Please have a look at this answer which is the neat and clean way to retrieve the data you've got there. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36264522/3145960. And yes, this is very unusual that your code is working in emulator and not working in real device. Can you please have a close look in your logcat and check if its getting an exception for any reason? It would be better if you could provide any repeated logs from your logcat

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your suggestion, I will follow it in the future questions.

Comment: The fact that `System.out.println(itemsList.size());` prints `0` is expected, since the data hasn't loaded yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this fact makes me think that the reason the emulator loads data is that it is much slower than android device. Am I correct?

Comment: Nope, that could only have explained if one prints 0 and the other not. It shouldn't make any difference in *whether* a device gets the data. I'm lost on that too.