# Understanding if data exists in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following to fetch a username from Firebase. But in this case, how do I get to know, if the username exists or not.

```
Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("<Firebasae_URL>/Users");
Query query=firebaseRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo("username");
```

Comment: This question already has an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36256978/3145960  See the `dataSnapshot.exists()`.

Comment: How do I handle it, when I use addChildEventListener.

Comment: See the answer posted

Comment: Using a `ChildEventListener` in this case won't be possible. The methods of that listener will get called **when** a child is added/deleted/moved/changed, while you are look to see **if** a specific child exists. You'll need a `ValueEventListener` as @ReazMurshed says is the way to detect client-side if a specific element exists.

Comment: Note that a pure client-side solution has inherent race conditions. See this [answer from Kato for a complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase). You'll have to translate the JavaScript to Java, but given that the Firebase SDKs have the exact same structure between these technologies, that should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in your case the code should be like this, to find an username exists in your database.

```
Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("<Firebasae_URL>/Users").child("username");
firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener) {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // User Exists
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to check if a query return value was

```
let docRef = db.collection('videos').select('id').where('id','==',quoteData.id);
docRef.get().then(function(doc){              
    if(doc.size > 0){
        // return value
    }
    else{
        // no return value
    }
})
```