# What is the best way to check if key exist in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if some key exists in my database, I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401490/4107223):

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasChild("name")) {
    // run some code
   }
 }
});
```

But my question is, is this way effective or it is better just looking for the child and check if it is not null? like this:

```
DatabaseReference savedItems = bDatabase.getReference().child("CHILD1").child("CHILD2");
if(savedItems == null { //do something }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second snippet won't work. You're not listening for anything.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so there is not another way to do this?

Comment: Your second snippet is currently not doing anything, so it's hard to say what's more effective. That said: downloading a bunch of JSON to [check if a specific key exists](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+check+if+key+exists) is hardly ever the most efficient way to do so. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826429/understanding-if-data-exists-in-firebase/36826793#36826793

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for clarifying me this.